# Running ProcessBuilder at runtime, only get part of BufferStreamReader

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I got problem when running jar file inside other jar using ProcessBuilder at runtime, the problem is, i only get only parts of stream output, here part of my code

```
String[] command = {  "java","-cp",fileJar.getAbsolutePath(),
                     "a.b.c.Class","-x",fileGram.getAbsolutePath(),   
                      "-o",GIFdir.getAbsolutePath(),"/","-d","xzf","-ver"};
ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( command );
pbaw = probuilder.start();
try {
  String line;
  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new     
  InputStreamReader(pbaw.getInputStream()));
  while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line); 
  }
  input.close();
  pbaw.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

in commad i mean, run a.b.c.Class from fileJar inside jar app with options : -x, fileGram inside jar app, -o, GIFdir directory, -d, xyz, -v. I get **complete output** in command console, but **only parts of output** when using process builder in jar app, why can this happens, help me please !!!

Comment: Could some of the output be to stderr? There are *two* output streams - one for standard output and one for error output

Comment: what you mean there are two output stream, running command at console is fine and smooth, but not in application, only parts of output i got, why?

Comment: He means there are two streams. See the ProcessBuilder Javadoc. An output stream and an error stream.

Answer (score 0):

This question is tough to answer without more details.  Caveat: In my experience, `ProcessBuilder` and `Process` can be tricky to use well.  Always a corner case lurking...

1) You say: *running command at console is fine and smooth*

Ok.  Run again at command line twice with this command:

- `jar x y z 1> stdout.txt`
- `jar x y z 2> stderr.txt`

Can you confirm stderr.txt is zero bytes?
Ideally, you should "pastebin" those two files and make available in this question.

2) Try to also read all bytes from STDERR via `Process.getErrorStream()`.

3) Finally, try to read bytes instead of characters from STDOUT and STDERR.

```
...
{
    ...
    String stdout = readInputStream(process.getInputStream());
    String stderr = readInputStream(process.getErrorStream());
    ...
}
...

public static String readInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    Charset cs = Charset.defaultCharset();  // or something different
    while (true) {
        int readCount = inputStream.read(buffer);
        if (-1 == readCount) {
            break;
        }
        String x = new String(buffer, 0, readCount, cs);
        sb.append(x);
    }
    String y = sb.toString();
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Yes, both of you're right, i make mistake when getting fileGram.getAbsolutePath() to run, after i check using getErrorStream, Thank You all guys, you're the best.